# Text result file for nunit test cases

Tags: c#, nunit

> I want text format or document result  or complete log for test cases running into NUnit.
>   for all passed and failed test cases with detail. how can i get this?

Comment: Don't you want to give feedback, if it helped? The same for many of your posted questions???

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventListeners](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=eventListeners&r=2.5.8) for this purpose.

Comment: can you please help me to know how to use or implement the  EventListeners?

Comment: Ask a search engine of your choice, there may be many examples. As a first result, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441430/get-list-of-failing-tests-from-nunit).